# Facing problem with for loop in java, Not getting desired result

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] arr = new String[] { "A", "B"};
    for (int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
        System.out.println("Item:" + arr[a]);
        
        String[] aar1 = new String[] { "1", "B"};
        for(int b=0;b<aar1.length;b++) {    
        System.out.println(aar1[b]);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting output as:

```
Item:A
1
B
Item:B
1
B
```

How can I get Output as:

```
Item:A
1
Item:B
B
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a nested loop, you should iterate both arrays with the same loop:

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "A", "B"};
String[] aar1 = new String[] { "1", "B"};
for (int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    System.out.println("Item:" + arr[a]);
    System.out.println(aar1[a]);
}
```